# IE9 and AJAX - List Not Refreshing (ASP.NET and MVC3)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

Im new to Web Development and its principles so apologies if my question does not seem clear.

**Story So Far......**

Im writing an Open Source application to learn ASP.NET MVC3. Now im at the stage where im creating my CRUD controller to allow me to create some new Types. Now I have created a SiteAdmin Controller which holds my Dashboard, with has a View. The View will contain **tabs**  . I have been learning how to handle tabs using the following blog post and JQuery UI

http://ericdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/jquery-ui-tabs-and-aspnet-mvc/

I have decided to use the AJAX example to handle my tabs, whereby I pass an index parameter to a Controller Action Method called **AjaxGetTab** . This method (as per the blog post) returns a Partial View for the required Type. Within the Partial View there are **Create** Controller Action Method's, for e.g. CreateTransactionType (HttpPost), which create new records.

**"Stop the waffling what is the problem"**

The problem is that my list within the tab on the view doesn't refresh after the Create method is finished. This problem only exists in IE9 (Only IE i have tested) **but** Chrome and Firefox work, i.e. the list refreshes.

I have checked the Database records exists.

My code is here:

*JQuery in Dashboard.cshtml:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        getContentTab (1);
    });

    function getContentTab(index) {
        var url='@Url.Content("~/SiteAdmin/AjaxGetTab")/' + index;
        var targetDiv = "#tabs-" + index;
        var ajaxLoading = "<img id='ajax-loader' src='@Url.Content("~/Content")/ajax-loader.gif' align='left' height='28' width='28'>";

        $(targetDiv).html("<p>" + ajaxLoading + " Loading...</p>"); 

        $.get(url,null, function(result) {
            $(targetDiv).html(result);
        });
    }
```

*SiteAdminController AjaxGetTab Method:*

```
    /// <summary>
    /// AJAX action method to obtain the correct Tab to use.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Tab number</param>
    /// <returns>Partial View</returns>
    public ActionResult AjaxGetTab(int id)
    {
        string partialViewName = string.Empty;
        object model = null;

        //--Decide which view and model to pass back.
        switch (id)
        {
            case 1:
                partialViewName = "_TransactionType";
                model = db.TransactionTypes.ToList();
                break;
            case 2:
                partialViewName = "_DirectionType";
                model = db.DirectionTypes.ToList();
                break;
            case 3:
                partialViewName = "_UserType";
                model = db.UserTypes.ToList();
                break;
            case 4:
                partialViewName = "_CurrencyType";
                model = db.CurrencyTypes.ToList();
                break;
            case 5:
                partialViewName = "_tabError";
                break;

        }

        return PartialView(partialViewName,model);
    }
}
```

*SiteAdminController CreateTransactionType Method:*

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateTransactionType(TransactionType model)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.id = Guid.NewGuid();
                model.RecordStatus = " ";
                model.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.TransactionTypes.AddObject(model);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
        }
        catch
        {
            return PartialView("_tabError");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your

```
$.get(url,null, function(result) {
     $(targetDiv).html(result);
});
```

By:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: url,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
    $(targetDiv).html(result);
  }
});
```

The problem is that IE caches ajax requests, so by setting cache: false in the settings it should work.

Comment: Thanks Charles for the speedy answer. I will give that a whirl now and let you know in a mo.